# Flutter web not loading on Gitlab Pages

Tags: flutter, gitlab-ci, flutter-web, gitlab-pages

I managed to build and deploy my project to Gitlab pages, but when I try to access it, it's blank.
Here is the repo: https://gitlab.com/grabtools/content_check 
You can see in CI/CD the pipeline passed and the artifact is in `public`.

I'm new to web and just playing around with flutter so I have no idea what's wrong.

Thanks

Comment: the url: https://grabtools.gitlab.io/content_check/

Comment: try to change the base-href with your projectName like `--base-href /repo_name/`

Comment: could you be a bit more specific, like what file in the project and where in that file that I need to update. Sorry, I'm an iOS dev and have no idea what these things are @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your `--base-href /repo_name/` and  build like

```yaml
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - flutter build web --release --web-renderer html --base-href /content_check/
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [deployment/web](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web)